# Anatomy of a Load Balancer Response

Tags: http, httpresponse

My load balancer is returning this:

```
10.99.100.999 - - [11/May/2017:23:22:09 +0000] "GET /<some long url> HTTP/1.1" 302 246 0.489 ms
```

What is the `246` number? Looking at various such entries that number changes, but I don't know what it's meant to imply, and I don't know how to search for it - most explanations don't seem to show any concrete examples that identify or even show that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is in the [Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format), that would be the number of bytes transmitted to the client in response.